# How to install hook procedure that monitors keystroke messages (WH_KEYBOARD_DLL or WH_KEYBOARD) using Easyhook C++

Tags: winapi, hook, unmanaged, easyhook

I'm using **[Easyhook](http://easyhook.github.io/index.html)** to hook keystrokes, but I don't understand how Easyhook works. How to install a hook to hook [KeyboardProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)) (callback function).
This is API of the  [LhInstallHook](https://easyhook.github.io/api/html/M_EasyHook_NativeAPI_LhInstallHook.htm):

```
static void LhInstallHook(
    IntPtr InEntryPoint, 
    IntPtr InHookProc, 
    IntPtr InCallback, 
    IntPtr OutHandle
)
```

Comment: You linked to documentation, that answers your question. If that doesn't help you, it's unlikely to help you, if we repeated the documentation for you.

Comment: @IInspectable In [Easyhook's tutorial](http://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/nativeremotehook.html), `IntPtr InHookProc` which implemented from **`GetProcAddress(GetModule(TEXT("kernel32")), "Beep")`**. Beep is WinAPI, which is located in the kernel32 but KeyboardProc is a callback function. How to **`GetProcessAddress`** it?

Comment: Sometimes it is required that you understand the underlying concepts to use a library. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks).

Comment: "*I don't understand how Easyhook works*" - which is the root of your problem. You choose the wrong solution to explore. EasyHook is meant for hooking other functions, particularly Win32 API functions, it is not meant for hooking keyboard events. You need [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) instead. See MSDN's documentation on [Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks) for more details

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yup, you are right. I will start with `SetWindowsHookEx()`. Thank you for your comment

Comment: If you have any question when use `SetWindowHookEx()`, please feel free to tell us.